# Error message when compiling ..Rmd to pdf in R Studio with TinyTex

Tags: r, knitr, tinytex

I am trying to knit an .Rmd document to pdf in R Studio 1.4.1104 on Linux Ubunutu 20.04. This worked fine then stopped working with no obvious cause and the error message:

`` ! You can't use `\end' in internal vertical mode. \enddocument ...cument/end}\deadcycles \z@ \@@end ``

I tried Yihui Xie's recommended [debugging procedures](https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/) and the verbose output said no LaTeX packages were missing.

I would be grateful for any advice on what to try next.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I have rebuilt my .Rmd file, running pdf knit after adding each chunk of text or block of code and the error has now disappeared. i am not any wiser about why the .Rmd is now compiling to LaTeX without errors, but it is so my short term problem is solved, thanks.